# Union of two finite sets is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

§7.3 #1

> Let $A$ and $B$ be a pair of disjoint finite sets. Use induction to prove that if $A \approx m$ and $B \approx n$, then $A\cup B \approx m+n$. 
>   Conclude that the union of two finite sets is finite.

This problem is from Pinter's [A Book of Set Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486497089).

please help

Comment: Map the elements of $A\cup B$ as: $\{1,2,\cdots ,m\}$ to the elements of $A$ and the $\{m+1,m+2,\cdots ,m+n\}$ to the elements of $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If either $A$ or $B$ is empty, answer is clear. So let $A$ and $B$ be non empty, that is $m, n \geq 1$. We will fix $m$ and use induction on $n$. We have map from $A$ to $ 
\lbrace 1,2,3 \ldots m \rbrace $.

Base case $n=1$: $B$ has 1 element disjoint from $A$, map this element to $m+1$, and thus we get a map from $A\cup B$ to $ 
\lbrace 1,2,3 \ldots m+1 \rbrace $.

Assume the statement is true for any set (disjoint with $A$) with $n$ elements, now we need to prove for $n+1$. Split $B$ into two sets one with $n$ elements and other with 1 element. I will leave the conclusion for you.

Comment: If the answer for the empty set is clear, that is a good reason to use *that* as base case, instead of treating it as special case and starting with the base case $1$. Unless the logic used in the induction step fails for $0\to1$, of course, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. The mind always start with $n=1$. But it is good that you mentioned "unless the logic used in the induction step fails for $0 \rightarrow 1$".